# How to save to database and publish atomically? ( all or none )

Tags: architecture, microservices, event-sourcing

I'm trying to implement microservice architecture to our application (basically an ecommerce) and one of the challenges that I can't really find a good answer for (despite being so many similar questions about) is how to:

- Create an entity in database
- Publish an event to event-bus

at the same time (atomically, so basically all or none).

## What I found so far

I came across similar questions and what I found so far is that solving this problem directly, is impossible. but there are workarounds:

#### Creating an `events` table

When inserting to the database, we can take advantage of `ACID` transactions to insert an event with `NOT PUBLISHED` status along with the `entity` itself and a background service can check whether all events inside `events` table has been published or not.

Cons that I can think of:

1. We might publish an event multiple times (imagine publishing the event but failing to update the database)
2. Since we might publish an event multiple times, the eventstore will have same events multiple times, so it would make event-sourcing harder.
3. Consumers need to implement a way to detect duplicate events.
4. What about service's which don't have transactional component like `ACID` in relational databases?

I just want to add something to the third con, Let's say I'm choosing this path, how do I detect if an event has already been processed or not?
If there's some sort of entity involved, I can check whether the `version` on the entity matches receiving event, but what if there's no entity? or the event is indicating to create an entity or anything else?

#### Only publishing the event

We only publish the event and make the service to listen for self-published events, this way another handler(within current service) can make current's service's database eventually consistent.

Cons that I can think of:

1. Imagine we are attempting to create an order, I want to return an `orderId` so the client can keep track of order's status by periodically requesting with given `orderId`, this way we don't have anything to return to the client.
2. Since the service's database is not consistent and is going to be eventually consistent, other services might assume this data is already saved/processed in current service while it's not.
3. Imagine the entries must be inserted inside a table and right after returning `OK` status to the user, another concurrent request, creates a similar record inside the database, and now our current request is going to fail because of an unique constraint in the database.

---

These are the things that I found so far, I'd really appreciate any tip and thank you for reading this far.

Comment: You're touching on some really difficult problems (exactly-once delivery, atomic updates, integrity with eventual consistency). In general, these cannot be solved. But you can often structure your architecture to get a good-enough solution for your scenario. E.g. you can't ensure that an event is published exactly once, but you can guarantee that a non-failing consumer will process events exactly once (by tracking IDs of processed events and discarding duplicates). Failure is less of a problem for idempotent operations that can be retried. Databases can upsert instead of insert. And so on.

Comment: Some of the design techniques that can help mitigate these problems are [eventual consistency](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) and the [saga pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html).